# I need to find the longest ascending array,im kind new to c++

Tags: c++

Example: `Array{2,3,4,7,8,9,10}`
I need to find the longest one:
Answer: `{7,8,9,10}` and write `"The longest=4"`

*code*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x[100],n,k=0;
    cout<<"Introduceti n=";cin>>n;
    cout << "Introduceti elementele tabloului:" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"n["<<i<<"]=";cin>>x[i];
    }
    cout<<"Elementele tabloului:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<x[i]<<setw(5);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Cel mai lung sir de ordonate crescator:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(x[i]+1==x[i+1]|| x[i]-1==x[i-1]){
                cout<<x[i]<<setw(5);
                k++;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Lungimea este:"<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what i have tried,but i don't know how to determine all the possible line lenghts.

Comment: what did you try? Hint: you need a loop, a counter for the current lenght of the ascending subsequence and remember the longest length encountered so far, thats all

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: This are the details,sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: your code looks for array elements whose difference is 0 or 1, while ascending only requires  `>=`. Also "how to determine all the possible line lenghts." do you need to find the longest or all possible lengths?

Comment: just the longest

Comment: it needs to specificly be in ascending order,like 2,3,4,5 not just ascending

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work & thinking, I've coded the solution of your problem. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int longest = 1, streak = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] - array[i - 1] == 1) {
            streak++;

            if (longest < streak) {
                longest = streak;
            }
        } else {
            streak = 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Longest array: " << longest << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above program gets the size of the array dynamically and checks if the current iterator of array is equal to its previous value, if so, then add otherwise reset and it'll go till the last. You can add/remove arrays, it's totally flexible.

> **Output:**
>   `Longest array: 4`

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Dudes,thanks a lot,I modified it a bit for some of my needs,but it works perfectly.Thanks you very much;

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13};

    //get the size of the array
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    //stores the number of the current streak
    int longest = 1;

    //stores the biggest streak
    int biggest = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        if(array[i] - array[i - 1] == 1) {
            longest ++;
        }
        else if(biggest < longest) {
            biggest = longest;
            longest = 1;
        } else
            longest = 1;
    }

    cout << "Longest array: " << biggest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```